# ContourPlot: Styling contour lines

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I can plot the curve corresponding to an implicit equation:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + (2 y)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

But I cannot find a way to color the contour line depending on the location of the point. More precisely, I want to color the curve in 2 colors, depending on whether x² + y² < k or not.

I looked into ColorFunction but this is only for coloring the region between the contour lines.
And I was not able to get ContourStyle to accept a location-dependent expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use `RegionFunction` to split the plot in two:

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot[x^2 + (2 y)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < .5], 
  ContourStyle -> Red], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 + (2 y)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 >= .5], 
  ContourStyle -> Green]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 I removed my solution (almost identical to yours) after I realized that you had solved it a full hour earlier than me.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this

```
pl = ContourPlot[x^2 + (2 y)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
points = pl[[1, 1]];
colorf[{x_, y_}] := ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[x, {-1, 1}]]
pl /. {Line[a_] :> {Line[a, VertexColors -> colorf /@ points[[a]]]}}
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. It enables the user use a continuum of colors, which is a nice complement to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This does not provide a direct solution to your question but I believe it is of interest.

It is possible to color a line progressively from within `ContourPlot` using what I think is an undocumented format, namely a `Function` that surrounds the `Line` object.  Internally this is similar to what `Heike` did, but her solution uses the vertex numbers to then find the matching coordinates allowing styling by spacial position, rather than position along the line.

```
ContourPlot[
  x^2 + (2 y)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  BaseStyle -> {12, Thickness[0.01]},
  ContourStyle ->
   (Line[#, VertexColors -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"] /@ Rescale@#] & @@ # &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

For some of the less adept, less information is more. Time was wasted browsing for a way to set the color of contour lines until I chanced onto Roelig's edited answer. I just needed ContourStyle[].

```
Show[{ContourPlot[
     x^2 + 2 x y Tan[2 # ] - y^2 == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3.2, 3.2}, 
     ContourStyle -> Green] & /@ Range[-Pi/4, Pi/4, .1]}, 
 Background -> Black]
```